# I get a bin forlder instead of a Script folder when creating a venv

Tags: python, python-venv

I try to follow this: (no real need to read this)
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/issues/4787

The command `python3` does not work for me, but when I just use `python` I get:

[image]

So since that is 3.8 and 3.8 is supported for what I wan't to to I guess that should be fine.

Ok when I enter `-m venv C:\python-envs\ml-agents` in command prompt I get the following:

[image]

The documentation from here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html states that:

> It also creates a bin (or **Scripts** on Windows) subdirectory containing
> a copy/symlink of the Python binary/binaries (as appropriate for the
> platform or arguments used at environment creation time).

I end up with a bin folder. The content of that bin folder looks like this:

[image]

Now my question is, should I be woried that I have a bin folder instead of a Scripts folder and that everything I have todo in python for the past 4 years never seem to work no matter on what machine I am?

And second, Is this enough for activation?

[image]

Comment: No, you should not worry at all. Whatever is inside the virtual environment is just there to provide the functionality; you should not want or need to look inside it at all.

Comment: You should generally not `cd` into the env; just run `.\ml-agents\bin\activate` from the parent directory of the virtual environment.

Comment: Please copy-paste the code/error and format it as a code in your question instead of adding screenshots of them.

Comment: @clankill3r NO.